# AVR/C code meaning

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

I was presented with following C AVR code by one of my colleagues:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

#define byte uint8_t

byte button[8]; 
byte play[8];
byte licz;
byte pind_in;
uint16_t freq[8]= {3822, 3405, 3033, 2863, 2551, 2272, 2024, 1911}; 
uint32_t count[8];

int main (void)
{
  DDRD = 0; 
  PORTD = 0xff; 
  DDRB = 0b00000010; 

  while (1)
  {
    pind_in = PIND; 
    licz += 16;

    for (byte i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      button[i] = !(pind_in&(1<<i));
      if ((button[i]) && (play[i] < 255))
        play[i]++;
      if ((!button[i]) && (!(licz)) && (play[i] > 0))
        play[i]-- ;

      count[i] += freq[i];
      if ((count[i] & (0x4000)) && (play[i]))
        PORTB = 0b00000010;
      else 
        PORTB = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that it's sound generation based on AVR microcontroller, but I'm unable to determine why is licz+=16 used in infinite loop, and what's the algorithm behind the rest of it. Is anyone here able to decrypt it?

Comment: Whitespace is free, and it would make this a lot easier to read.

Comment: @user694733 Ditto. by mistake I posted a wrong comment [now deleted]. Dear Sven, Please put some effort on making the code human readable.

Comment: The whole point of me posting this question is being unable to understand the principle behind it

Comment: @Sven The point of the comment was that if code presentation is difficult to read, it is hard to decipher. Anyway, now that Mehrwolf has done this for you, you should clarify what exactly is the problem. What have *you* understood so far about it?

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward what is so hard about it?

Answer (score 2):

I see it like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define byte uint8_t
// frequency table for each used HW button (scaled to main loop timing)
uint16_t freq[8]= {3822,3405,3033,2863,2551,2272,2024,1911}; 
byte button[8];    // HW button state
byte play[8];      // amplitude ... realy there is just single amplitude output but this makes time hysterezis of sound to filter out the glitches
uint32_t count[8]; // counter for frequency generation
byte licz;         // just counter for hysterezis generation amplitude is increasing 16x faster then decreasing
byte pind_in;      // variable for HW buttons/key-press detection

int main(void)
   {
   // probably configuration of IO port of the MCU (was not specified...)
   DDRD= 0; 
   PORTD=0xff; 
   DDRB= 0b00000010; 
   // inf loop of main process
   while(1)
      {
      pind_in=PIND;  // read the HW buttons state
      licz+=16;
      for (byte i=0;i<8;i++) // loop through all buttons/frequencies
         {
         button[i]=!(pind_in&(1<<i));                           // extract button state on/off
         if (( button[i])&&          (play[i]<255)) play[i]++; // if keypressed increase amplitude up to max
         if ((!button[i])&&(!licz)&&(play[i]>  0)) play[i]--; // if not decrease amplitude until zero
         count[i]+=freq[i];                                      // update frequency generator counter
         // alternate the speaker/buzzer
         if ((count[i]&(0x4000))&&(play[i])) PORTB=0b00000010; else PORTB=0;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

there is much to improve in this code

- like no need for button[]
- adding PWM for real amplitudes and sinwave generation
- adding wavetable for specific instrument
- better timing via timers/counters
- and much much more

Comment: That's great and I'm really grateful for your answer. Would you be able to determine the idea of licz+=16; thing? Could it be possible that it's used to debounce?

EDIT: OK, now I've read the comments. Thank you really much.

Comment: @Sven the `licz` is for sound play hysterezis, but I think Mehrwolf explain it better. it is just counter that is increasing with some frequency (16*main_loop_period) so it hits zero every 256/16 iteration. When you hit a button then the `play` is maxed in 16 iterations if you release it then it will decrease to zero in 256 iterations of main loop and during this time the sound is still playing. this emulates piano ... plays a while when key is released.

Comment: "_probably configuration of IO port of the MCU_". That is correct. `DDRD=0` configures all the pins of port D as inputs (DDR = data direction register). `PORTD=0xff` activates the internal pullup resistors: one can infer that the buttons are wired between the port D pins and ground. `DDRB=0b00000010` configures PB1 (pin 1 of port B) as output, and the rest of port B as inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know whats connected to your AVR, so this is only an educated
guess here.
Let's assume that a sound is output, while `PORTB.2 == 1` and silence otherwise.

This `PORTB` bit is set as long as `play[i] > 0`. `play[i]` is increased when
`button[i]` is set, which probably is an external push button or something
similar. When the button is released, `play` counts down to zero again. 
Probably this shall make last the sound a bit longer than the button press.

The `licz` variable makes down-counting slower. Every 16-th loop (assuming
that byte == 8 bit), `licz` will be zero again and the decreasing `play` is skipped. If you change `licz += 16;` to `licz += 128;` for example, you skip decreasing in every 2nd loop, making the sound last even longer after a button release.